# sql query running time - can this be optimized?

Tags: sql

this sql query runs on SQL Server.
execution run takes 22 seconds, and i wonder if this code can be optimized, so it runs faster

```
select id,  mdt8_status,  mmmin1st_status,
  CASE
  WHEN mdt8_status IS NULL OR mmmin1st_status IS NULL  
    THEN NULL
  WHEN  mdt8_status = 0 OR  mmmin1st_status = 0  THEN 0
  WHEN  mdt8_status = 2 AND  mmmin1st_status = 2  THEN 2 
  ELSE 1 
  END AS total_status  
  FROM 
    (select id ,
        CASE 
            WHEN mdt8 is NULL THEN NULL WHEN mdt8 < 17.45346 OR mdt8 > 29.69626 THEN 0 
            WHEN mdt8 < 22.76841 OR mdt8 > 26.86486 THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
            END AS mdt8_status,
        CASE 
            WHEN mmmin1st is NULL THEN NULL 
            WHEN mmmin1st < -4.315884 OR mmmin1st > 3.630149 THEN 0 
            WHEN mmmin1st < -0.354075 OR mmmin1st > 3.219826 THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
            END AS mmmin1st_status   
        FROM cells_FULL) AS subquery
```

Comment: The title (and post) should reflect what the code does, not what your review request is. Please take a moment to walk us through the purpose of the code--it's hard to review and optimize something without a bit of background and context for what its intent it, what data is in the database, what your current performance problem is, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe the purpose of your code.

Comment: Please also add the table definitions, including and indexes that are defined.